# Problems reading a .xls file using Perl Win32::OLE under Cygwin

Tags: perl, excel, cygwin, win32ole

I have been fighting with this one for two days, I cannot find the solution and I'm getting frustrated. While using the code below under Cygwin I get this error

**OLE exception from "Microsoft Office Excel": Excel cannot access 'Empty.xls'.

The document may be read-only or encrypted.
Win32::OLE(0.1703) error 0x800a03ec
    in METHOD/PROPERTYGET "Open" at m:/In/make_excel.pl line 24**

The thing is that under the DOS prompt it is working perfectly. The file is not readonly of course. I'm guessing there is some problem with the file format interpretation. 
Any hint? It would be highly appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE::Variant;
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';
$Excel = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Excel.Application') ||
   Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application');
$Excel->{'Visible'} = 0;        #0 is hidden, 1 is visible
$Excel->{DisplayAlerts}=0;  #0 is hide alerts
# Open File and Worksheet
my $Book = $Excel->Workbooks->Open('C:\Empty.xls'); 
...
```

Comment: As I said running under the DOS prompt it works, only when run from cygwin it does not. What is so especial about cygwin? Maybe some permissions are not right setup

Comment: ok, I found that the perl distribution is making the difference. Under DOS prompt the ActiveState version is used and under cygwin the built one is used. Could someone explain this?

Comment: Finally, I just downloaded the Win32::OLE again, I did a local installattion and now it works!!! Something is screwed up with the built in installation. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

MS Excel requires MS Windows paths.

The problem is in the

```
my $seedProject = "$ENV{'HOME'}/Empty.xls";
```

Use '\\' instead of '/' : Excel works only with windows paths.
Check path delimeters in $ENV{HOME} also.

Answer (score 1):

It is very important to keep the regular Windows universe and the Cygwin corner of it well insulated when working in Cygwin. It is entirely possible that you actually did not have a Cygwin `Win32::OLE` installation to begin with and somehow ActiveState's lib directories where being added to the `@INC` of Cygwin's `perl` (via an environment setting or something else). That will mostly work for pure Perl modules, but anything that uses XS will be messed up.

By installing `Win32::OLE` in Cygwin, you may have put it in the `@INC` ahead of ActiveState's lib directories, and therefore allowed Cygwin's `perl` to locate the correct module. However, you should run something like:

```
$ perl -e 'print "@INC\n"'
```

On the Cygwin prompt to ensure that only Cygwin paths appear in it.

Also, you might want to install Cygwin's `perl-libwin32` package via `setup.exe`, rather than building modules manually.